# Building boost 1.57 with gcc4.7.1

Tags: boost, building, gcc4.7

I'm trying to build Boost 1.57 with GCC 4.7.1 bundled with CodeBlocks on Win7 64b.

I did this :

```
mkdir c:\boost\build
cd c:\boost\tools\build\v2
bootstrap.bat gcc
b2 install --prefix=C:\boost\build
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\boost\build\bin
cd c:\boost
b2 --build-dir=C:\boost\build toolset=gcc --build-type=complete
```

And I get this :

```
error: Name clash for '<pstage\lib>libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_57.a'

error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
error: these incompabile properties:

error:     -  none
error:     -  <linkflags>-shared-libgcc <linkflags>-shared-libstdc++

error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Why not ask on the Boost users list instead of here?

Comment: I did. But I'm not sure if it comes from Boost or MinGW and Boost doesn't officialy support MinGW on Windows as I read on the web.

Comment: That's an error from the Boost build system, and Boost definitely supports mingw

Comment: Ok, I just have to wait on boost list then.